# Can I use SPARQL to query DBPedia for information about Wiki pages such as page length or number of times an article was accessed?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

```
    SELECT *
WHERE {
?Person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Comedian> .
?Person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?Person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate.
?Person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageLength> ?weight.
}
```

I had thought that the above code would, when plugged into [snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/), generate a dataset that included the length of the Comedian page being queried. Instead, it's generating an empty dataset. By contrast, the code below generates a non-empty dataset, but one which does not include the page length.

```
    SELECT *
WHERE {
?Person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Comedian> .
?Person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?Person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate.
}
```

Is there a way to query DBpedia for information about a Wikipedia page that isn't included in the page itself, such as the length of the page or the number of times it is accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there *is* such a property declared (e.g., see http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageLength), it doesn't appear to actually be *used* in describing any resources.  E.g., the following query returns 0:

```
select (count(*) as ?n) { ?s dbo:wikiPageLength ?l }
```